# Update XML Sitemap with PHP on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

i have the following Problem. I have searched many Sites for a solution, but i am so a newbe here...
Maybe someone can help me:

We have an Recruiting Software where we can create job offers. This Recruiting Software use an api to publish these jobs on our career Site. Our Site runs at Wordpress. This Plugin works on our page.
So the Job Post will eb on our career Site.

But I also want to automatically generate an xml sitemap so I can submit it to Google Search Console. And everytime (or at least every 4 hours) the sitemap should crawl our jobs or is up to date.

I have found a script for a custom XML-Sitemap on Wordpress, because XML-Plugins (like Rankmath or Yoast) doesnt recognized the "api" jobs.

```
This is a php code for the XML-Sitemap:
namespace RankMath\Sitemap\Providers;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

class Custom implements Provider {

    public function handles_type( $type ) {
        return 'custom' === $type;
    }

    public function get_index_links( $max_entries ) {
        return [
            [
                'loc'     => \RankMath\Sitemap\Router::get_base_url( 'custom-sitemap.xml' ),
                'lastmod' => '',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function get_sitemap_links( $type, $max_entries, $current_page ) {
        $links     = [ 
            [ 'loc' => 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' ],
        ];

        return $links;
    }

}
```

With every `loc` there is a new row with the right url.

**So my first problem is, that i need there an loop**

The API use an open json swagger. So if i type the following "curl get" request in the url-bar i get as response the following shortened text/plain:

```
{
  "LastUpdateTime": "2022-08-23T12:22:54.3839484Z",
  "Items": [
    {
      "DatumAb": "2022-08-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",
      },
      "LinkSlug": "AAAA",
      "StelleUuid": "1111",
    },
    {
      "DatumAb": "2022-08-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",
      },
      "LinkSlug": "AAAB",
      "StelleUuid": "2222",
    },
    {
      "DatumAb": "2022-08-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",
      },
      "LinkSlug": "AAAC",
      "StelleUuid": "1111",
    }
  ],
  "TotalItems": 44
}
```

Every Page (generate from the API) at our Homepage has the same Structure:
[www.test.de/**LinkSlug**/**StelleUuid*](http://www.test.de/**LinkSlug**/**StelleUuid*)*
So for e.g.: [www.test.de/AAAC/1111](http://www.test.de/AAAC/1111)

Now there is my second Problem: how can i merge `Linksslug` and `StelleUuid` in `loc`?

The third Problem: How can i automate this Process? So that every 4 hours the XML-Sitemap is actual?

I dont where i have to start.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there any CPT where these jobs are being stored? Or they are fetched and presented when anyone browses the careers page?

Comment: Sry, what means CPT? I know that for the jobboard (Career Site) there is a WordPress Caching function. The Caching function has a timelimit, till it will be updated by itself. So, no these jobs are not fetched by the user.

Comment: What I meant was: Are these jobs stored on the Career Site or they are just displayed via an iframe on a specific page?

Comment: They are stored on the Career Site.

Comment: And by looking at the code I believe you're using Rankmath as your SEO plugin right?

Comment: Yep. Using Rankmath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247505/discussion-between-richard-zelzner-and-vinay-jain).